# Does simplesaml provide any API for IdP as it does for SP?

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I know that `SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple` class is provided for SP side operations but I can't find the API for IdP side operations like assertion creation and sending the message to the SP's assertion consumer service.
Does that mean there is no exposed API and simplesaml handles this internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSP handles it automatically. You can follow the code in [SSOService](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/master/www/saml2/idp/SSOService.php) for how it receives AuthNRequests and responds if you needed to customize something.